# I am using Jersey and i am getting this error "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception "

Tags: spring

This is my code and i am using MyEclipse Juno with Apache Tomcat 7.0. and
I am using Jersey and i am getting this error "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception ".
I have used @Path,@GET and @Produces with importing javax.ws.rs.*, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType, javax.servlet.* . Then anything I left..???  :-

**index.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 
   4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html><head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>JAVA RESTful Demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   JAVA RESTful Service
   </body>
   </html>
```

**readme.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html><head><title>Read Me</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>READ ME</h1>
   </body>
   </html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.
     container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-  class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>REST</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**v1_status.java**

```
    @Path("/v1/status")
    public class v1_status {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String returnTitle() throws ServletException{

    return "<p>Java Web Servises</p>";  
}}
```

Comment: Are you aware thath you are not using Spring MVC annotations?

Comment: I found out the solution which is in web.xml i.e. <param-value>REST</param-value> should replace with the package name.

Comment: I added the package name but the issue us still there