# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name > [com] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com]

Tags: tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I am developing a simple jersey web service from dynamic web project type, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DY46f-LZ0M) tutorial. So far I have the following code:

**ServiceStatus.Java (in package au.com.biting.bolat.status)**

```
package au.com.biting.bolat.status;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/v1/status")
public class ServiceStatus {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle() {
        return "<p>Java Web Service</p>";
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>au.com.biting.bolat</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>au.com.biting.bolat</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

When I run this service in tomEE, the root path (*http://localhost:8080/au.com.biting.bolat/*) works fine but the path *http://localhost:8080/au.com.biting.bolat/api/v1/status* gives the following error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com] is not bound in this
>   Context. Unable to find [com].
>     org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
>     org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
>     org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
>     javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$2.stepInto(CDIExtension.java:308)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.diveIntoJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:285)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.lookupJerseyConfigJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:305)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:181)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:95)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have tried several fixes including cleaning nd building the project, building the project from scratch and have checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537730/i-am-using-jersey-and-i-am-getting-this-error-http-status-500-servlet-init), but the errors are unrelated. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know wich version of jersey are you using, so I consider the last one. Try to change the name of some properties inside web.xml since you are using the older ones, the tutorial is a bit old:

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>au.com.biting.bolat</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
```

For more details you can visit the [official documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html).

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of jersey are by default configured for glassfish, to make it working in tomee you need to set in conf/system.properties:

```
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW why not just using cxf and let tomee deploy your webservices? (= why adding jersey there, this is not needed)